# Angular: *ngFor in parent or child component?

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns, parent-child, angular-components

Please look at my app-wall template below. I'm wondering if I should go for `<app-brick *ngFor="..."></app-brick>`, or `<app-bricks>` with an *ngFor inside its own template. Is there a best practice when it comes to this, or is it completely case dependent?

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-wall',
  template: `
      <app-brick *ngFor="let brick of bricks"></app-brick>

      or

      <app-bricks></app-bricks>
  `
})
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-brick',
  template: '<div> I'm a brick! </div>'
})
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bricks',
  template: '<div *ngFor="let brick of bricks"> I'm a brick! </div>'
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct, according to me passing `bricks` array to child component and displaying it like  `'<div *ngFor="let brick of bricks"> I'm a brick! </div>'` is better since child will be rendered only once.

parent.ts

```
<app-bricks [bricks]="bricks"></app-bricks>
```

child.ts

```
@Input() bricks : any[]

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bricks',
  template: '<div *ngFor="let brick of bricks"> I'm a brick! </div>'
})
```

Comment: What if there are some changes to be done for certain instances of the component ? Then it will make sense to keep distinct instances of the component instead of simply relying on multiple *ngIf and *ngFor directives inside the child component. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @adibro500 I put my views here according to the scenario given in the question, with other cases, there will be pros and cons of both the ways ofcourse :)

Comment: @adibro500 if you need to change specific `brick`, then your component will handle logic based on `brick` property. That's the reason component exists.

Comment: @Florian but each instance of the component can also carry its own state right ? I have used components array instances and they can actually maintain their unique state. For example, the global variables can act like they have been encapsulated from one component instance from another. In such cases, it makes sense to use array of child components.

Comment: @adibro500 It all depens of the use case. For example, you can have a main component `bricks` that handle general logic and your __bricks template__ will display `brick` components like that `<app-brick *ngFor="let brick of bricks"></app-brick>`. And you handle specific logic for brick inside brick component. You should use what suits the requirements